How to display columnGroup only on the last page using primefaces datatable?
<p:columnGroup type="footer"> <p:row rendered="#{}"> <p:column footerText="TOTAL" style="text-align:left" /> </p:columnGroup> 
I use the paginator, and if I have 11 items in my list, the column group is displayed on both the first and last page. The only solution is to remove the paginator, but I'd like to avoid that.
I've tried different options, including rendered, booleans, but I can't seem to solve it. Can anyone kindly help me. Sorry for my English.
I would like to display the record with the totals only on the last page of the table.
